# Joint density of Independent and identically distributed Exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, exponential-distribution

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,…,X_{10}$ are iid exponential random variables. What is the joint density of $X_1,…,X_{10}$ at $x_1,…,x_{10}?$ Is it the product $$f_{(X_1,\dots,X_N )}(x_1, \dots , x_n) = f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)\dots f_{X_n}(x_n)$$ or is it different for an exponential?

Comment: $f_{(X_1,...,X_N )}(x_1, . . . , x_n) = f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)· · · f_{X_n}(x_n)$ is true for any independent random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any independent random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with respective probability density functions $f_1(x), \dots, f_n(x)$ their joint probability density function is $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$. Note that $X_i$ do not need to be exponential and do not need to have the same distribution. Instead, the form of the joint distribution is the defining property of [*independence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)).